# foreach function instead of for loop

Tags: f#

I have the [following code](https://github.com/dharmatech/treasury-gov-tga-top.fsx/blob/66df97d2295fa07ae5349c4cc0bbe1a7690a96b1/treasury-gov-tga-top.fsx#L51-L52):

```
for elt in result.data do
    display_record elt
```

I factored out this pattern into:

```
let foreach proc seq =
    for elt in seq do
        proc elt
```

so that I can instead say:

```
result.data |> foreach display_record
```

## Questions

- Is there already a function that does this?
- Would the above approach be considered idiomatic F#?

Part of the reason I'd like this more concise expression is that I use it in other places interactively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection function `iter` is what you usually use instead of a `for` loop if you are interested only in the side effects, i.e., the function you want to apply to each element returns `unit`.

In particular, your collection `filtered` is a `TGARecordData array`,  so [`Array.iter`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule.html#iter):

```
Array.iter: (('a -> unit) -> 'a array -> unit)
```

With `Array.iter`, you can write instead:

```
filtered |> Array.iter display_record
```

It will apply your `display_record` function to every element of the `filtered` array. `display_record` is only for the side effects it produces: printing a `TGARecordData` value.